# Where to store secret keys when using Polymer + Firebase?

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-security, slack-api

I'm developing a web application using Polymer + Firebase. In my app, I'm trying to integrate it to Slack. In order to obtain an access token from Slack, I need to make an api call to Slack with the client secret key (generated by Slack).

The question is, where/how should I store this client secret key? Hardcoding this key in my Polymer app sure sounds like a big security no no.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use Environment Variables for Firebase secrets

To set your environment variables, create a `functions/.env` file of the format ...

```ini
ACCOUNT=xxxx
API_KEY=yyyy
```

You can override these variable for specific project aliases. So if for example you'd aliased your project deployment instances as `dev`, `stage`, `prod` ... you can override the settings in your `.env` file with similar files named as `.env.dev`, `.env.stage` or `.env.prod`.

Then in local emulator or deployed code you can use:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const apikey = process.env.API_KEY;
const url = `https://hooks.slack.com/services/${apikey}`
// call Slack API
```

For full details refer to

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

### Don't use remote config for secrets!!

The Firebase documentation is (or was) rather vague about whether remote config was intended for use as a secure store. It should however NOT be used for storing secrets since it's designed to be accessible and used on both client and server.

At time of writing, the Firebase document did not make this security issue clear. So Firebase team ... please add a security warning at the top of the documentation for Remote Config. I know this has tripped up many Firebase developers who've assumed that "configuration" meant "secure configuration".

Answer (score 1):

Storing a secret in your client-side code sounds like a very bad idea. Any malicious user can get it there.

Any other way that requires access to the secret on the client is similarly flawed.

The only solution is one that doesn't require the secret to exist on the client, so one that involves running code in a trusted location. Typically this will be a server, but don't overestimate how much hardware you need to run such code on. Requiring a server in this case is about trust, not about bigger hardware.

See pattern 2 in this [article about common application architectures on Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html).

Comment: Thanks. It does seem Pattern 2: Firebase-powered app with server code is the only solution where "You want your app to integrate with third party APIs (like Twilio to send an SMS, or SendGrid to send an email)." its still a bit hazy on how to get it all working though....

Comment: To clarify .. Are you saying that `functions.config()` is accessible on the client side?  If so then the Firebase docs don't make this very clear all. I though that you'd only use remoteConfig API for client side config.